# Kubernetes EKS: transition to new NodeGroup

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

On an EKS cluster, I want to transition from the existing NodeGroup (say NG1) to a fresh NG2 (with spot instances). NG1 will remain as fall-back.

Do I really need to play with Node Affinity in my deployments and make them "prefer" NG2, and then rollout-restart?

Or is it enough to set the desired size for NG1 to a very low value, say just one node per AZ, thereby "nudging" the workload to migrate to NG2?

Answer (score 1):

Node affinity sounds better choice to me

Comment: Perhaps  but it's a laborious process to add affinity settings to a long list of deployments and stateful sets, both my own plus various add-ons.